# Applicability of coulombs law for objects in different dielectric media

Tags: forces, electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law, dielectric

Is the Coulombs law applicable for inter-medium interaction?
Consider the example image
shown below

[image: Electroscope(representation) whose leaves I dipped in oil and water, and charged it heavily,using a van de graaf generator]

How can one deduce the angles the bobs might make if they are in different dielectric medium?What impact would the dielectric constant of the medium have on the respective angles?

Can I apply the coulombs law to derive the equilibrium force? If yes what  would the field lines look like?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use the Coulomb's law where different mediums are present. You will need to use these equations:
$$\begin{align} \mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P} \tag 1\\
\oint\limits_{S} \mathbf{D} \cdot \mathbf{\hat n} dA = Q_{free} \tag 2
\end{align}$$
Here, $\mathbf{D}$ is displacement field, $\mathbf{E}$ is the net electric field, and $\mathbf{P}$ is polarization, that is, electric dipole strength per volume. In a dielectric material, both positive and negative charges are present, however, when there is no electric field, the fields due to these charges cancel each other. When there is electric field, on the other hand, they are separated from each other a tiny bit, and thus they create a lot of small dipoles. $Q_{free}$ is the total free charge inside the closed surface over which you take the integral; that is, the charge that does not belong to the dielectric material present.

You cannot determine the net electric field solely from these two equations though, you need to make further assumptions to get a result. One of those assumptions is that the medium is linear. So we can write
$$\mathbf{E} = {\mathbf{D} \over \epsilon_r\epsilon_0}$$
So if we know the displacement field, we can find the electric field, and the displacement field only depends on the free charge. But, there needs to be a symmetry in the system in order for us to be able to calculate the displacement field using second equation, yet there is no such symmetry in our system. As an approximation, we may assume that spherical symmetry exists around the charges. Then the strength of vector on the first charge $\mathbf{D_1}$ would be $D_1 = {1 \over 4 \pi} {q_2 \over r^2}$. $r$ here is the distance between charges. Similarly, strength of $\mathbf{D_2}$ would be $D_2 = {1 \over 4 \pi} {q_1 \over r^2}$. From here on, you can do the rest of calculations to find the equilibrium positions of the charges.